# Как сделать два text view в одном элементе меню NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, android-menu

Добрый день, товарищи разработчики 
Как сделать два text view в одном элементе меню NavigationView? вот как-то так должно получиться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется, на скрине либа какая-то для левого меню. Наверное в ней есть для этого методы. Стандартный `NavigationView` без аццких хаков так не умеет. Т.е. вам либо эту либу юзать либо кастромный адаптера к Listview/RecyclerView пилить и использовать его вместо `NavigationView`. А вообще ваш вопрос не очень корректно составлен и подробнее не ответить.

Comment: Да, на скрине библа другая, но проблема в том, что её юзать нельзя, только стандартный NavigationView

Comment: Тогда у вас большие проблемы. Попробуйте такой костыль https://stackoverflow.com/a/36694906/3212712